# Firebase multiple subaccounts per user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I couldn't find information on this. I have an iOS app, written in swift. Firebase is my storage and database place. For now, I authenticate my users with email and password (no social media auth). My question is - is it possible after they've created their account to create many sub accounts? And if so, how do I track those (meaning, which is the primary account and how to switch between them - something like twitter and the way it allows to use multiple accounts and switch between them)?

My goal is to allow each user to have/create multiple accounts, make 1 account primary and the rest would be secondary accounts. Not sure if Firebase allows any of this though. I know this is broad description, but I want to make sure that this is indeed possible before I try to do anything like that. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use combination of Firebase Authentication + Database for managing primary and secondary accounts.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I do authenticate them and then create a user profile in the database, I'm just not sure how to create more accounts. Obviously, it should be based on 1 authentication (i.e. email/pass account) and then in the database I have to somehow create multiple sub accounts with some sort of reference? This is where I'm lost

Comment: Yes, you can use `uid` reference which is unique ID generated against a user (email/password). Sub-accounts node can contain sub-accounts for a particular user. Of course, it won't be as secure as Authentication.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan That makes sense, ok, thank you!